# After running composer update my whole laravel 5.8 site broke

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, digital-ocean, laravel-5.8

I am runing laravel 5.8 with php 7.2 on nginx with ubuntu 18, 6 hours ago I ran composer update and my server stopped compiling blade into html and everything just got broke..... I have been trying and searching for a solution but now I and fed up, if anyone has faced this issue before please help me out.

[image: This is how my current website look like]

even now when I run composer update or dump-autoload all blade files are printed in the cmd 
[image]

```js
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.0",
        "spatie/laravel-honeypot": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.35"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
          "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it again and clear all caches/sessions. You may also want to generate new key

Comment: I ran it like more than 10 times. (composer install) and it just gives me the same issue again and again. so far have cleared view cache, application cache, clear-complied.

Comment: I would like to also mention that when I first ran composer update it gave me this ( M bin/carbon "2.28" has modified file ) on nesbot/carbon

Comment: could you paste your composer.json?

Comment: have you tried to restart your server?

Comment: composer json attached. and yes, vladd. I have restarted my server 4 times exactly.

Comment: @Vladd were you able to figure out anything strange in the file?

Comment: Had to re-upload everything, now it is working.

Comment: SOrry for late response, want online. Nothing strange i can se in your composer.json. I am glad you sorted it out :)